# i don't want the input field to show already entered data when we double click in the input field..what should i do?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Web Page </title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

actually what i wanted once you fill the name and click submit and when you again open the page to enter the data, then if you double click in the input field then it display the previously enters data. i don't want that what should i do.

Comment: Use autocomplete = "off"

Answer (score 0):

You need to do more research. You probably didn't know how to word it properly, but as @kannan said, it is as simple as putting `autocomplete="off"` at the end of your `<input/>` fields.